# Trying to return a Map but an Iterable is currently being returned

Tags: scala

Why is my val `pairOpt` a `Option[Option[String,String]]`?

I am trying to have it so it returns `Option[(String, String)]`.

```
def blah(..): Map[String, String] = {

  val map: Map[String, String] = //
  val boolTry = Try(map.getOrElse("key1", "").trim.toBoolean)
  val intTry = Try(map.getOrElse("key2, "").trim.toInt)

  val pairOpt: Option[Option[(String, String)]] = for {
    b <- boolTry.toOption
    i <- intTry.toOption
  } yield {
    val res: Option[String] = (b, i) match {
      case (true, 1) => Some("a")
      case (false, 2 | 3 | 7) => Some("b")
      case (true, 5 | 9 | 11) => Some("c")
      case _ => None
    }
    res.map("foo" -> _)
  }

  map ++ pairOpt // map + ("foo" -> "c")

}
```

The return value is also currenly `Iterable[Product with Serializable]` when I want it to be `Map[String,String]`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You it to return Map[String, String] or Option[(String, String)]? The iterable is returned, I believe, because it's only possible type that satisfies adding a Map[String,String] to a Option[Option[String,String]].

Comment: @pedrofurla I want to the for-comp to return Option[String, String] and the method to return Map[String, String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an `Option[Option[..]]` because you have two "layers" of "optionality" here that you have to **flatten**:

- If one of `boolTry` or `intTry` is a `Failure` - you'll get `None`
- Else, if they're both `Success` but their values don't match anything, you'll get `Some(None)`
- Otherwise, you'll get `Some(Some(..))`

More generally, given a `opt: Option[V]`, the type of an expression of the form:

```
for {
   x <- opt
   .. 
} yield {
   val y: T
   y
}
```

is `Option[T]` - because it translates into `opt.flatMap(...).map(...)` which preserves the "external" structure (be it an `Option`, `List`, `Seq` etc.). In your case, `T = Option[(String, String)]`, so the result has the type `Option[Option[(String, String)]]`. To fix this - you can use `flatten`:

```
val pairOpt: Option[(String, String)] = (for {
    b <- boolTry.toOption
    i <- intTry.toOption
  } yield {
    // same as you did... 
  }).flatten
```

Which would also fix the issue with the method's return type (now `map ++ pairOpt` will have the type `Map[String, String]` as expected).

To avoid this call to `flatten` - perhaps a cleaner way to achieve the same would be:

```
val maybeTuple: Option[(Boolean, Int)] = boolTry.flatMap(b => intTry.map((b, _))).toOption

val pairOpt: Option[(String, String)] = maybeTuple.flatMap {
  case (true, 1) => Some("a")
  case (false, 2 | 3 | 7) => Some("b")
  case (true, 5 | 9 | 11) => Some("c")
  case _ => None
}.map("foo" -> _)
```